# Unable to add Careers Link on my profile: invalid link or username

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

Browsing the new user page, I tried to edit my profile, and to link my careers profile.
First, my Stack Overflow profile says that my Careers

> "Profile [is] Found, but Hidden"

For information, my careers profile is in public visibility.

When I check the "Show Careers link on my profile" checkbox, and then Save changes (for this community or all of them, it's the same problem), I've got this error:

> **Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: The Stack Overflow Careers link or username entered does not appear to be a valid Stack
>   Overflow Careers link or username.**

Comment: Hidden means hidden on Stack Overflow - i.e. not displayed on your profile.

Comment: This should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check for validity of user names was incorrectly rejecting those with a `.`.

This has now been fixed and will roll out in the next build.