# Unable to link Personal Careers Page to Stack Overflow Profile

Tags: support, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

Disclaimer: I read the following SO questions and answers given to them but still no luck finding a solution that actually works.

- [Why am I unable to link my StackOverflow Career profile to SO profile?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290488/why-am-i-unable-to-link-my-stackoverflow-career-profile-to-so-profile)
- [Unable to add Careers Link on my profile: invalid link or username](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290571/unable-to-add-careers-link-on-my-profile-invalid-link-or-username)
- [Link from SO user profile to careers profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91557/link-from-so-user-profile-to-careers-profile)

I am unable to link my SO careers page into my actual SO profile. When I click on `Discover Stack Overflow Careers` button on my profile page, I am being taken to my personal SO Careers page but I still couldn't see the button turned into this:

[image: linked]

from this one:

[image: not linked]

in my SO profile page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I've found the way how to do that. It is funny though as I am pretty sure it  wasn't there yesterday so I am assuming SO developers are still working on it.

The answer is, in **Edit Profile & Settings** tab, there is a small checkbox with a text *"Show Careers link on my profile"* next to it and you should check that box in order to link your profile.

[image]

Comment: How to update existing carrers page. Means once i sync data with likedin. Now i updated severel things with liknedin.  So how to update it??

Comment: This was so hard to find...it's kinda ridiculous.

Comment: Is that setting on SO profile? I cant see it :(
.. oh wait its there now. Not sure if toggling my career privacy helped, or making sure the email addresses matched on both profiles.

Comment: I don't see this, nor does it say it can find my profile. It simply says 'No careers profile for this account; click the link to..' (cut off text, doesn't fit in the button). The button next to it takes me to my career page.

Could it be an issue that I use Google as my login method on both SO components?